# Is it a good programming habit to have an object of a class as an attribute of the same class?

Tags: java, c++, user-interface, interface

I created a class in JAVA which I only need one object for. So I defined the class as final and the constructor as private and one object of the same class as private final static along with another object which is from another class:

```
public final class GUI implements ActionListener{

    private final static GUI gui = new GUI();
    private final static GElements ge = new GElements();

    private GUI() {

    }
```

In the main function I would like to use the gui object to do the operations like such:

```
GUI.getGUI().create();
```

Now my question is: Can this be considered good programming or because of the fact that the object gui keeps including more and more GUI objects is not?
A GUI object having a GElement object along with another GUI object which itself has another GElement along with another GUI object which has ...

Would this work for C++ aswell?

Comment: please read up on the singleton design pattern to correctly understand how you should do this.

Comment: Google "singleton pattern".

Comment: _"The object gui keeps including more and more GUI objects"_ , since the object is static, it is a member of the class and not an object. So no, there is only one.

Comment: @user3672700 "The object gui keeps including more and more GUI objects" This idea you mention is called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), and no, this isn't that. This is using a static member. And yes, this would work for C++.

Comment: Also, be cautious about singletons as vague as "GUI", lest they become [god objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)